include all data in extended tables in Power BI report
I'm pulling data from a table in D365 using Power Query in Power BI, I'm using cross-company=true to bring over the data from all the sites but when I extend a table in the data I only see my defaults data all the other sites are blank?
Can someone help me am I not including somethig in my ODAT Connection or is it something else?
